# интеграция c++ и python

Tags: python, c++, sql, django, сервер

создаю сервер на python(django) и хочу интегрировать в него сервер на с++ для более быстрых операций (например алгоритмов и БД) и у меня вопрос как я могу это сделать есть ли статьи или тп?

Comment: Скорее имеет смысл сделать наоборот - интегрировать в С++ сервер движок python для интерпретации. Внезапно, это уже сделали - nginx unit и т.п.

Comment: ну в принципе я бы мог использовать эти фреймворки, но я студент и хотел бы сам (со своей командой) написать подобное пусть оно будет немного хуже или хуже, но зато  я бы получил опыт